# Can VSCode close all subfolders after closing the parent one as PhpStorm does?

Tags: visual-studio-code, directory, phpstorm

I have a question if VSCode can close all subfolders after closing the parent folder as PhpStorm does for me. Eg: I'll open the `node_modules` folder and go through some folders inside. After closing the `node_modules` folder it would be pretty nice to close all the opened folders in `node_modules`.

Is that possible?

Comment: Do you mean wrapping the node_modules folder in file explorer should wrap all unwrapped subfolders? No, there is no setting to enable that, and I could not find an extension for it either.